# How do I alter sequences in Postgres with BDR

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-bdr

We are doing some database migration in Postgres (in two-node BDR cluster).

Because of some unrelated issue, sequence on certain tables are out of sync and need to be reset.

We tried the `setval` (and `ALTER SEQUENCE`) but both failed.

```
SELECT setval('mytable_id_seq', (SELECT MAX(id) FROM mytable));
```

> ERROR: cannot call setval() on global sequence public.mytable_id_seq

```
ALTER SEQUENCE mytable_id_seq RESTART WITH 48800;
```

> ERROR: ALTER SEQUENCE ... restart is not supported for bdr sequences

Comment: You can only advance the sequence, by calling `nextval` in a loop on it.